# Look for file in subfolders in nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am changing the file structure.
Some of the urls, that were previously available at root level of the site are now moved to a subfolder.

So I have an `$uri`.
I `try_files $uri @check_subfolder;`
If the file (normal .html file) still exists at the root level, or it's url is written properly, then `try_files $uri` works as it should.
But if the file is moved to a subfolder, then I enter

```
location @check_subfolder {
}
```

And if here I just make a redirection `rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host/articles$1 permanent;` then everything is still perfect.
But I want first to check if the `$uri` really exist in the `/articles` subfolder or not.
So I do

```
location @check_subfolder {
    if (-f "/articles${uri}") {
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host/articles$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

It just falls down to error 404. Redirection doesn't happen. Without the `if` redirection works. So obviously the problem in the way how I formulate the condition.

`if (-f "/articles${uri}")` doesn't work.
`if (-f "/articles${request_filename}")` doesn't work.
`if (-f "/articles/${request_filename}")` doesn't work.
`if (-f /articles/$request_filename)` doesn't work.
`if (-f /articles/$uri)` doesn't work.

I obviously write wrong concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is that I didn't think that `-f` looks for file in filesystem, not for a web-page, so I had to include `$document_root`.
So now it works like

```
location @check_subfolders {
    if (-f $document_root/articles/$uri ) {
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host:8090/articles$1 permanent;
    }
}
```